# How do I connect to Jboss through the CLI tool?

Tags: jboss, out-of-memory, command-line-interface, jboss7.x

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final.  I’m trying to connect to the CLI tool, but keep getting this OutOfMemoryError.  In my standalone.xml config, I have

```
<management>
    <security-realms>
        <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local"/>
                <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-realm>
        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
            <authentication>
                <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
                <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authentication>
            <authorization>
                <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
            </authorization>
        </security-realm>
    </security-realms>
```

I connect to the CLI tool like so with the error …

```
bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh --controller=192.169.1.118:9999
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.handleSafe(CommandContextImpl.java:551)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.interact(CommandContextImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:270)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:294)
```

Anyone have any suggestions?  How do I connect to JBoss through the CLI tool?

**Edit:** My memroy settings within standalone.conf are set through JAVA_OPTS like so

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx10240m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

**Edit 2** K, added the memory settings to the last line of the jboss-cli.sh file.  Got past “connect” but then got the OutOfMemoryError shortly after …

```
bin]$ ./jboss-cli.sh 
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
[disconnected /] connect
Authenticating against security realm: ManagementRealm
Username: admin
Password: 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.handleSafe(CommandContextImpl.java:551)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.interact(CommandContextImpl.java:1113)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:243)
    at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:270)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:294)
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Where are you getting 7.1.3.Final from? The last release of JBoss AS was 7.1.1.Final.

Comment: What is your OS and exact JVM version?